# all possible combinations between certain amount of digits c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, combinations, combinatorics

I need to find a function that works like this:

```
 int[] matches = getAllPossibleCombinations(
    int lengthOfEachIntReturnedInArray, 
    List<char> typesOfElementsUsedInCombinations);
```

input elements would be these (this is just an example):

- `int lengthofeachintreturnedinarray = (int) 2`
- `List<char> typesofelementsusedincombinations = {a,b}`

then the output would have to be (in a string array):

> aa
>
> ab
>
> ba
>
> bb

Each individual output element in the array must have a length defined by the first argument in the method (in this case 2) and must contain all possible combinations between the given letters in the second argument

I have seen something about powersets, should I use them, or should `foreach` loops suit the job?

! the proposed question with answer above is NOT the same, it doesn't use set lenghts !

Comment: What requirement you have for doing this

Comment: bonds to atoms (chemical)

Comment: do you want the second argument to be a `List<string>` or a `List<char>` ?    i.e., can the individual elements be more than one character each ?

Comment: you are right - I'll change it to List<char> ; thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll direct you to Eric Lippert's [article](http://ericlippert.com/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/) on implementing a [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) in Linq, which he writes as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

Using this, you can implement your method like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetAllPossibleCombinations(
    int lengthofeachintreturnedinarray, 
    IEnumerable<string> typesofelementsusedincombinations) 
{
    return Enumerable
        .Repeat(typesofelementsusedincombinations, lengthofeachintreturnedinarray)
        .CartesianProduct()
        .Select(strings => String.Concat(strings));
}
```

Comment: and this will exactly return the values noted above?

Comment: @user2698666 yes, it will.

Comment: I tried the code but it throws an error at the .CartesianProduct() line in the second block of code : "Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' does not contain a definition for 'CartesianProduct' and no extension method 'CartesianProduct' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' could be found" How do I solve this?

Comment: @user2698666 It's an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). To use it like this, it must be defined as a public (or internal) static method in a static class. You may also need to include a reference to the class's namespace. If you don't want to use it as an extension method, use it as a normal static method instead: `CartesianProduct(Enumerable.Repeat(...)).Select(...);`.